# Validate number from database

Tags: java, jsf

I use this Java Server Faces validator for profile edit form. But I came to this problem. For example I have account with ID 45. If I submit the form I will get error that this ID already exists.

```
public void validateAccountID(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws SQLException
    {
        Long l;
        String s = value.toString().trim();

        if (s.length() > 18)
        {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "  Value is too long! (18 digits max)", null));
        }

        try
        {
            l = Long.parseLong(s);
            if (l > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    "  '" + l + "' is too large!", null));
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            l = null;
        }

        if (l != null)
        {
            if (ds == null)
            {
                throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
            }

            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs;
            int cnt = 0;
            try
            {
                conn = ds.getConnection();
                ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT count(1) from ACCOUNT where ID = ?");
                ps.setLong(1, l);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next())
                {
                    cnt = rs.getInt(1);
                }

                if (cnt > 0)
                {
                    throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "  '" + l + "' is already in use!", null));
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException x)
            {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    "  SQL error!", null));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ps != null)
                {
                    ps.close();
                }
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.close();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                s.isEmpty() ? "  This field cannot be empty!" : "  '" + s + "' is not a number!", null));
        }
    }
```

So I need to implement some logic when I open account profile page with account 45 when I click submit to allow his own ID to successfully to edit the account. Can you propose some so0lution?

Comment: so you need to allow the creation of duplicated accounts?

Comment: @Peter Penzov You do ps.executeUpdate(); when (cnt > 0)

Answer (score -1):

In your edit form you should not throw an exception when find out that this id exists in the database. This is what is expected from an existing account - to have a record in database. Your validation should be prior user accessing the edit form namely on login. Ones he is logged you set some flag on user Bean as logged and here just check if the user is still logged in order to make changes on his own profile.
1 On log in 
  - check if the user exist in database and the provided password is correct; 
  - set boolean flag logged  in UserBean to true
2. On submition edit form:
 - check if the user is still logged and validate the rest fields of the form